# How does the heat-activated blowing agent in foaming plastic filament survive the manufacturing process?

Tags: everyday-chemistry, plastics, applied-chemistry

Special 3D printer filaments are available with blowing agents mixed in. These blowing agents cause the filament to foam as it is extruded, causing the resulting structure to have a much lower density.

https://hackaday.com/2020/02/17/bubbly-filament-works-better-than-you-think/

How do these blowing agents survive the manufacturing process? Since the filaments are spun out of almost-molten plastic, would that not trigger the agent? Or is the agent's reaction temperature able to be tuned so narrowly that it survives the filament extrusion process but not the printer melting process?

Comment: This thing you linked hardly tells any details.

Comment: @Mithoron I'm not sure I've ever seen any more details than user reports. https://www.cnckitchen.com/blog/testing-colorfabb-varioshore-tpu-foaming-3d-printing-filament mentions sometimes baking soda is used, and https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/full/10.1002/advs.202105701 just mentions the general process. So it's possible this is a poorly posed question, if it's the case that there's not a single blowing agent which is typically used.